# Generator of the cyclic Galois group $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}[\xi_{n}]/\mathbb{Q})$

Tags: galois-theory

I would like to know what is a generator of a $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}[\xi_{n}]/\mathbb{Q})$ cyclic group if we know that the elements of the group are automorphisms such as

$\sigma_{\ell}:~\mathbb{Q}[\xi_{n}]\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}[\xi_{n}]\\ 
\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}\\
z~=~a_{0}+a_{1}\xi_{n}+...+a_{k}\xi_{n}^{k}\rightarrow z(\ell)~=~a_{0}+a_{1}\xi_{n}^{\ell}+...+a_{k}\xi_{n}^{\ell k}
$

Thank you!

Comment: Is $n$ here the degree of the extension?   Or is $\xi_n$ notation for something else, like a primitive $n$-th root of unity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are taking $\xi_n$ to mean a primitive $n$-th root of unity, there is an isomorphism between $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}[\xi_n]/\mathbb{Q})$ and $\mathbb{Z}_n^\times$.

$\mathbb{Z}_n^\times$ is not always a cyclic group.  In particular, this group is cyclic if and only if $n$ is $2, 4$, any power of an odd prime, or twice any power of an odd prime.  If $\mathbb{Z}_n^\times$ is cyclic, then unfortunately there is no general algorithm to find a generator.

Answer (score 1):

The Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_n]/ \mathbb{Q}$, with $\zeta_n$ a primitive $n$-th root of unity is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/n)^{\ast}$, which need not be cyclic in general. It is cyclic, for example, for $n=p$ prime, with the Frobenius automorphism as generator.